# Open file dialog freezes the program when I try to use it

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, openfiledialog

I am using visual studio 2017 to create a windows form application, which I am trying to use OpenFileDialog to load an XML file.
When I first created the program everything works fine but after working and testing my code the application freezes when I launch the event to show the dialog.

I had this problem before where I was using Visual Studio 2015 and I could not find a solution.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
    
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ofdLoadXMLFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = ofdLoadXMLFile.SafeFileName;
                
        MessageBox.Show(fileName);

        lblFileName.Text = fileName;
        File.Copy(ofdLoadXMLFile.FileName, fileName);

        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());

        document.LoadXml(fileName.ToString());

        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(document);
        string result = document.ToString();

        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Connect To All\Desktop\result.json", jsonText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use breakpoints and know which line is causing the freeze.

Comment: So you still have the problem you had before.  OpenFileDialog and friends are somewhat risky components, they cause all of the shell extensions to get loaded into your process.  Programmer machines tends to have a lot of them, not always of the best quality.  One possibly quick way to escape is to change the jitter forcing so 32-bit extensions can't work.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit".  SysInternals' Autoruns utility is a decent way to locate and disable the bad one.

Comment: What is the value of the `.InitialDirectory` property? Is it set to a folder/share that is sometimes inaccessible? That would be roughly the equivalent of trying to navigate to an inaccessible folder/share in Windows Explorer via the address bar: `\\INVALID_ServerName\Departments\IT`... Explorer hangs until it gives up and reports that the folder/share is inaccessible.